# Google analytics code is included multiple times in a page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a Enterprise Trading site. I have included the `Google analytic's` code in every jsp of my site. Now the problem is since in my site some pages are included within other pages not using frames just by ajax call and changing the div contents. As a result the when a new page is loaded within the same page Google Analytic's wont be called since the entire page is not loaded, and the browser considers only page load to load the js, Not frame change. Can any one suggest a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution is use a global variable, like this:

```
if (! window.googleAnalytics) {
    window.googleAnalytics = true;
    // ga code here ...
}
```

Better alternative way is:

When I add Google Analytics on site, I wrote small js file, named google-analytics.js, here is contents:

```
function GoogleAnalytics(accountId, productionServerUrl) {
    var _gaq = window._gaq = window._gaq || [];

    if (window.googleAnalytics) {
        throw new Error("GoogleAnalytics tools already created!");
    }
    window.googleAnalytics = this;

    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.dummy = (window.location.hostname != productionServerUrl);

    // Work's only on production server and ignore sandboxes
    if (this.dummy) {
        return ;
    }

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', this.accountId]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
        ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        ga.onload = function() {
            //console.log("GA Loaded !!!!", this, arguments);
            window.googleAnalytics.getTracker();
        };
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
}

GoogleAnalytics.prototype.getTracker = function () {
    if (this.dummy) {
        return null;
    }
    if (undefined == this.pageTracker) {
        if (window._gat == undefined) {
            console.error("! Google Analytics script is not loaded !");
            return null;
        }
        this.pageTracker = window._gat._getTracker(this.accountId);
    }
    return this.pageTracker;
}

GoogleAnalytics.prototype.track = function () {
    if (this.dummy) {
        console.log(" >> GoogleAnalytics.track()", window.location.href, this, arguments);
    }
    if (this.dummy) {
        return ;
    }
    var tracker = this.getTracker();
    if (null == tracker) {
        return;
    }
    tracker._trackPageview();
}

if (undefined == window.googleAnalytics) {
    window.googleAnalytics = new GoogleAnalytics('UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'yoursite.ru');
}
```

This script must be loaded after jQuery.js loaded.
Insert, your GA-ID and site url in constructor's arguments.
You can call window.googleAnalytics.track(), after AJAX page load and url changed.
Good Luck!